# visual studio 2010 hangs on start typing

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

i installed some new addons, after awhile I noticed a little bit slowing in IDE

days later - Exactly today ;) - it is hanging every time I tried to type anything, so I disabled all the installed addons, but with no use...

any ideas??

Comment: Have you closed and re-opened VS after disabling the add-ins?

Comment: yes, and restart windows also

Comment: this happens only with files larger than 10000 lines of code? is kind of a bug ?

Comment: You could always refactor that code so it doesn't have 10,000 lines of code in one file :)

Comment: @Code Gray, No, actually I'm c# fan :)

Comment: @schummbo, Yes, you're right, but actually it is not just me in this project, and they're strong aid to the old school :D

Comment: I uninstall all the addons i've, (disable didn't help), now it works fine ... thanks

Answer (score 2):

try running in safe mode first

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241278.aspx